# Counting and the probability of functions from A to itself

Tags: probability, functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose a set A with N elements, I have to translate the statement:

The relation R corresponds to an injective function from A to itself

into a logical statement, and also find the probability of it holding.

For the first part, I tried ∀a ∈ A, ∀b ∈ A, (a, b) ∈ R ⇒ ( a = b ), which I am not completely certain on.

For the probability, I believe the number of injective functions would be N!, so then would the probability then be N! / ${N}^{N}$ ?

I also have a follow up question, where instead the statement in question is:

The relation R corresponds to a bijective function from A to itself such that given any input, the output is not the same as the input.

This one I am completely lost with. How should I be going about answering this question?

Answer (score 2):

> For the first part, I tried ∀a ∈ A, ∀b ∈ A, (a, b) ∈ R ⇒ ( a = b ), which I am not completely certain on.

No, that says that any element is at most related to itself. (If an element is related to anything that thing is itself).

A relation is an **injective function** when *every* element in the domain maps to a *single distinct* element in the codomain (a one-to-one mapping)

> For the probability, I believe the number of injective functions would be N!, so then would the probability then be $N! / N^N$ ?

Indeed. The codomain of an injective function is a permutation of the domain.

> The relation R corresponds to a bijective function from A to itself such that given any input, the output is not the same as the input.

This is a [*derangment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: I'm slightly confused on the way I should word my statement. If I want to describe a one to one mapping, can I instead say ∀a ∈ A, ∀b ∈ A, ((a, b) ∈ R ∧ (b, a) ∈ R) ⇒ ( a = b )? Also, in regards to derangment, is it different to an asymmetric relation?

Comment: A derangment is a reordering of an array where no member retains its original position.   So, for instance:  $\{(0,1),(1,0),(2,3),(3,2)\}$ is an example of a deranging injection over $\{0,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: One-to-one: Every element in the domain maps to exactly one element in the codomain, and every element in the codomain is mapped by exactly one element in the domain.